# Ruby shell command has different output than the shell

Tags: ruby, shell

When I run this from the terminal:

```
$ grep -rnw 'PageObjects::CompanySettings::InfoPage' spec/**/*_spec.rb  | cut -d: -f1 | uniq
```

It returns a single result:

```
spec/features/admins/change_payment_method_spec.rb
```

When I run this command (notice **InfoPage** is now **TeamPage**:

```
$ grep -rnw 'PageObjects::CompanySettings::TeamPage' spec/**/*_spec.rb  | cut -d: -f1 | uniq
```

I get one result:

```
spec/features/team_page_spec.rb
```

Now, when I go into `irb`, and use the backticks to call a shell command, I get output for the second command (TeamPage), but no output for the first command (InfoPage).

```
2.1.6 :001 > `grep -rnw 'PageObjects::CompanySettings::InfoPage' spec/**/*_spec.rb  | cut -d: -f1 | uniq`
""
2.1.6 :002 > # No result ^^
2.1.6 :003 >   `grep -rnw 'PageObjects::CompanySettings::TeamPage' spec/**/*_spec.rb  | cut -d: -f1 | uniq`
"spec/features/team_page_spec.rb\n"
2.1.6 :004 > # One result, as expected!
```

Can anyone help me figure out why this is?

Comment: No idea about your question, but curious why you're adding line numbers (`-n`) then cutting them off. `grep -rwl 'pattern'` should give you the same result, without `cut` and `uniq`.

Comment: NICE!

I just used a `grep` oneliner I found elsewhere to recurse subdirectories and match the filenames. 

Your way is much cleaner!

Comment: I've modified my original to now look like this, and based on Jorg's answer below, stopped using the strange wildcard pattern:

`grep -rwl 'PageObjects::CompanySettings::TeamPage' spec --include="*_spec.rb"`, and this now works correctly within Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that in your first example, the file is nested several directories deep, and that you are using the non-standard `**` wildcard.

My best guess is that your interactive shell supports that non-standard wildcard, but your batch shell does not.

One possible solution would be to use `find` instead of relying on shell wildcards. Another possibility would be to use Ruby, since you are already using Ruby anyway. (Note: `grep` is extremely optimized, so if you have a huge number of very large files, Ruby might be a bit slower.)

```
# Ruby's Dir class does support **
Dir['spec/**/*_spec.rb'].select {|filename|
  File.open(filename) {|file|
    file.each_line.any? {|line|
      line.inlcude?('PageObjects::CompanySettings::InfoPage')
    }
  }
}
```

[UNTESTED]

Comment: Interesting. I am using ZSH so that may just be the case. I would think that an `irb` session in a ZSH shell would use ZSH though?

Comment: `system`, backtick, etc. always use `/bin/sh` on Unix and `CMD.EXE` on Windows, even if your login or interactive shell is different (e.g. in Windows, the login shell is always `EXPLORER.EXE` and my interactive shell is PowerShell). The standard shell is documented in [`Kernel#exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec). On Debian and Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is Dash, which doesn't support `**`, and even on systems where `/bin/sh` is Bash, Bash actually disables most non-standard features when executed as `/bin/sh`. I assume zsh behaves similarly.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for clarifying that. Any ideas as to why it would work fine with the one command but the other one, with just a different word in the search query, would have different results? Marking your answer as the correct answer in any case. Thanks again!

Comment: Because the file is in the first directory down, and `**` is interpreted the same as `*` by a shell that doesn't have that non-standard feature. IOW: in both cases, `grep` only searches in files that are one directory down, but only in one case does it actually find the search string.

Comment: @jakeonrails: How could irb possibly recognize, whether it was invoked from a Zsh shell?